# If a search result is a place that only people who live in a certain area can visit, what's the best way of explaining that?

Tags: search, search-results, localization, geolocation

For example there's a community doctor's surgery in a town, it's free for people who live in town 1 and town 2.

As someone living in town 3 who has searched and found this community doctor's surgery but it won't be free or available to me, what's the best approach to explaining this?

---

**Updated with example**
Below is a very simplified example of what happens in the current process, I've shown the offline and online version as I think it's important to recognise it's directing people to a physical location.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more context, such as visual mocks that explain your specific use case, constraints, and details?

Comment: @MikeM added some more detail on the current flow. As you can see on the 'results page' there's a content warning that services might not be available. We could add additional postcode (zip code) validation some point after the initial search.

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is to ask for the zip code, or, if the user offers permission, add a "localize me" button as an alternative to asking for the zip code. If the service is unavailable let them know as early as possible, before commencing the flow.